# Does the light from Dawnbreaker affect sneaking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does the light that emits from the Deadric artifact dawnbreaker help enemies to see you like the light from spells and torches do?

Comment: wait do spells make you easier to detect? first time i have heard this if spells do then yes the sword would.

Comment: @IPhantasmI Not equipping spells, using spells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, yes. Even if the light emitted is very slight, any light that hits you or another enemy will help to give away your position. Of course, depending on how sneaky you may or may not get away with you attack.